# Translating RegEx from Javascript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I'm writing a tool -for private use- that reads a string. The containing string is full url encoded. Normaly I use [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) site for decode or encode a string. So I took a look at the source code. In the source of this, I found two regexpressions:

```
.replace(/'/g,"%27").replace(/"/g,"%22")
```

and

```
.replace(/\+/g,  " ")
```

I think the first does replace all `'` to `%27` and `"` to `%22`. Is that right? If not, what is the pendant in Java?

At second statement, I have no idea what does it mean and do. Can some explain it and what is the pendant Java?

I'm still an absolute beginner with regexpressions, so I hope the community here can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right about the first statement.

As for the second statement, it is replacing plus "+" signs by spaces " " (%20).

It is written as `/\+/`because plus "+" is a special character and has to be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
input.replaceAll("'", "%27").replaceAll("\"", "%22");
```

And

```
input.replaceAll("\\+", " ");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to. Because I could mark only one answer, you got +1 from me.